# hovering over ul does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anybody know why hovering over ul elements does not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/5/

```
<ul class="navi">
    <li> <a class='light'>
            Item1
            <div class="hover-name" style="display:none">
                Businesses
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a class='light'>
            Item2
            <div class="hover-name" style="display:none">
               Agencies
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>            
        Item3
        <ul class="hover-name" style="display:none">
            <li><a>hello</a></li>
            <li><a>hello2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to hover over the elements in the list and having other elements pop up when hovered over, but somehow it does not work when you hover over the ul "hover-name" element in the fiddle.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i wasnt very clear in the explanation sorry, if you look in the fiddle, you can hover over Item1, Item2, but not Item3

Comment: `Item3` doesn't have a `a.light`, or there is no *Anchor* tag with a class of *Light*.

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply hover event for last `li` seperately since your last `li` doesn't have any anchor with class `light` :

```
$('.navi > li a.light, .navi li:last-child').on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/7/)**

---

If you don't want to follow above way like in your comment, why not just target your `li` instead of the anchor:

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Samfr/8/)**

Comment: Thank you for your response! it works. How would i fix this if it was not the last child, like any random element?

Comment: @James You can just target your list item instead of the anchor. Check my update

Answer (score 1):

delete the

```
a class='light'
```

of the other 2 items, and change the

```
$('.navi > li a.light')
```

to

```
$('.navi > li')
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Felix's answer are good. You can also remove `a.light` from selector:

```
$('.navi > li').on("mouseover", function () {
    $('.hover-name', this).show();
}).on("mouseout", function() { 
    $('.hover-name').hide();
});
```